# How to implement "Marvellous Marble" (live wallpaper) from Google Pixel 2 into your own app?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app which shows a globe that spins on swipe. Right now I'm using WhirlyGlobe/mousebird but the problem is that I cannot use a custom background image with it. I can only change the background colour. So I want to replace it with the "Marvellous marble" (live wallpaper) from Google Pixel 2. Is there a library that I can use to implement it? Couldn't find it on searching for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try going through the file finder on the Google Pixel to enter the "wallpaper" file.  Then copy the file and use it for your needs? I’m a little confused also.